# Why is inserting entities in EF 4.1 so slow compared to ObjectContext?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

Basically, I insert 35000 objects within one transaction:

```
using(var uow = new MyContext()){
  for(int i = 1; i < 35000; i++) {
     var o = new MyObject()...;
     uow.MySet.Add(o);
  }
  uow.SaveChanges();
}
```

This takes forever!
If I use the underlying `ObjectContex`t (by using `IObjectAdapter`), it's still slow but takes around 20s. It looks like `DbSet<>` is doing some linear searches, which takes square amount of time...

Anyone else seeing this problem?

Comment: I somehow believe that the answer will be similar to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5917478/what-causes-attach-to-be-slow-in-ef4/5921259#5921259

Answer (score 132, accepted):

As already indicated by Ladislav in the comment, you need to disable automatic change detection to improve performance:

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

This change detection is enabled by default in the `DbContext` API.

The reason why `DbContext` behaves so different from the `ObjectContext` API is that many more functions of the `DbContext` API will call `DetectChanges` internally than functions of the `ObjectContext` API when automatic change detection is enabled.

[Here](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/11/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-2-when-is-detectchanges-called-automatically/) you can find a list of those functions which call `DetectChanges` by default. They are:

- The `Add`, `Attach`, `Find`, `Local`, or `Remove` members on `DbSet`
- The `GetValidationErrors`, `Entry`, or `SaveChanges` members on `DbContext`
- The `Entries` method on `DbChangeTracker`

Especially `Add` calls `DetectChanges` which is responsible for the poor performance you experienced.

I contrast to this the `ObjectContext` API calls `DetectChanges` only automatically in `SaveChanges` but not in `AddObject` and the other corresponding methods mentioned above. That's the reason why the **default** performance of `ObjectContext` is faster.

Why did they introduce this default automatic change detection in `DbContext` in so many functions? I am not sure, but it seems that disabling it and calling `DetectChanges` manually at the proper points is considered as [advanced and can easily introduce subtle bugs into your application so use [it] with care](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx).

Comment: @Ladislav: Your're right I didn't find this as I was only searching for insert problems :-(

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. I was actually calling context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false but I did it during database construction in the Seed() method. I thought this would set the default. I wasn't aware that I have to call it for each instance. Thanks!

Comment: @Hartmut: You could disable the change detection inside of the constructor of your derived DbContext, then you have it always disabled. But personally somehow this remark about "potentially introducing subtle bugs" when it is disabled makes me nervous. I have change detection on by default and disable it only in code blocks like yours where the performance boost is obvious and where I feel safe that it doesn't cause problems.

Comment: I agree, I was only testing some performance critical part of my application. In production code it's best to limit it to cases like bulk inserts etc.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.  Lots of information out there, but this cuts to the chase!

Comment: @Slauma That link is dead, afaict. Even with the parens added in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696177(v=vs.103).aspx

Comment: @TankorSmash: Thanks! I've replaced the first link by a link to another reference and removed the second link (can't find a replacement for this quote).

Comment: [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205.aspx) is a new copy of the link.

Comment: @emodendroket: Great, thank you! I've added the link to the answer.

Answer (score 12):

Little empiric test with EF 4.3 CodeFirst:

Removed 1000 objects with AutoDetectChanges = true : 23 sec

Removed 1000 objects with AutoDetectChanges = false: 11 sec

Inserted 1000 objects with AutoDetectChanges = true : 21 sec

Inserted 1000 objects with AutoDetectChanges = false : 13 sec

Comment: Thanks Zax. What are your results with 35,000 as per the question? You'll see that in the original question it tsates that the performance drops quadratically

Answer (score 12):

In .netcore 2.0 this was moved to:

`context.ChangeTracker.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;`

Answer (score 1):

Besides the answers you have found here. It is important to know that at the database level is is more work to insert than it is to add. The database has to extend/allocate new space. Then it has to update at least the primary key index. Although indexes may also be updated when updating, it is a lot less common. If there are any foreign keys it has to read those indexes as well to make sure referential integrity is maintained. Triggers can also play a role although those can affect updates the same way.

All that database work makes sense in daily insert activity originated by user entries. But if you are just uploading an existing database, or have a process that generates a lot of inserts. You may want to look at ways of speeding that up, by postponing it to the end. Normally disabling indexes while inserting is a common way. There is very complex optimizations that can be done depending on the case, they can be a bit overwhelming.

Just know that in general insert will take longer than updates.