# EF: Sql Compact 4 and identity

Tags: .net, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

As I know, EF didn't support Sql Compact identity fields. Hasn't it changed in Sql Compact 4 release?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes [it has changed](http://erikej.blogspot.com/2010/11/using-entity-framework-with-sql-server.html) but there are some [complains about performance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6642274/entity-framework-4-1-databasegeneratedoption-identity-performance).