# Is there any way to control AutoDetectChanges on SqlEntityConnection?

Tags: entity-framework, f#, type-providers

[This article](http://ilmatte.wordpress.com/2013/01/01/entity-framework-code-first-always-disable-autodetectchanges-when-importing-data/) provides some evidence that turning off AutoDetectChanges on your Entity Framework data context can provide a significant performance improvement when inserting large numbers of entities.

```
context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
```

However, the DataContext provided by the [SqlEntityConnection type provider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev11.query?appId=Dev11IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders.SqlEntityConnection%29;k%28DevLang-fsharp%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework,Version=v4.5%29&rd=true) doesn't seem to provide any way to control this setting.

There's no `context.Configuration` property, or `context.DataContext.Configuration` property. There is a `context.DataContext.ContextOptions` but it has nothing even resembling `AutoDetectChangesEnabled`.

The `DataContext` property on the type provider context is of type [`System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.aspx). Does anyone know of a way to influence this particular setting from there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I wrote a pretty similar article last year on detect changes performance which you can find here: http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2012/5/7/entityframework_performance_and_autodetectchanges My experience is mostly with DbContext (which wraps ObjectContext) but i did a bit of a search and found the following

[Why is inserting entities in EF 4.1 so slow compared to ObjectContext?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943394/why-is-inserting-entities-in-ef-4-1-so-slow-compared-to-objectcontext)

what this says is that ObjectContext doesnt actually do automatic change detection so this isnt something you should need to worry about. However you still do need to be aware that large object graphs will slow things down as is all snapshot tracking scenarios detect changes is required at some point, and this involves full enumeration of the object graph

Comment: Thank you for that information on the default behavior of ObjectContext. Chances are pretty good, then, that the Type Provider doesn't add any extra change detection over the default behavior, and I don't need to worry about this. Of course, the only way to be sure is to benchmark the type provider against a raw ObjectContext and/or a DbContext with and without AutoDetectChanges. If I get a chance to do that I'll update my question.

Comment: @JoelMueller yeah absolutally and i would be really keen to see the results if you do. I made a benchmarker which i used for my blog posts which is up on github if you want some pre-baked tests. I used the insert/update scenarios for that specific blog post. If you do end up using the benchmarker fork it and i will pull your new tests into the trunk

Comment: I used your benchmarker to run some comparisons, and for bulk insert the type provider is comparable to or better than DbContext with AutoDetectChanges turned off in every case. So problem solved - no need for that setting I was looking for.

Comment: @JoelMueller awesome thanks for the update and the additional tests ill pull them into the trunk soon