# EF Code First: is good to call DetectChanges just before SaveChanges?

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have read few articles ([article1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943394/why-is-inserting-entities-in-ef-4-1-so-slow-compared-to-objectcontext), [article2](http://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/entity-framework-increasing-performance-with-autodetectchangesenabled)) about Entity Framework that it calls DetectChanges many times, which makes it very slow when working with large amounts of data.

Can i, for example, disable the `autoDetectChanges` when i initialize the context, and just call `DetectChanges()` before calling `.SaveChanges()`?

Will the context recognize the inserted/changed/deleted entities?

```
var _dbContext = new ProjectContext();
_dbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

// add/edit/delete entities

_dbContext.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();
_dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

Should this approach work? or it may create hidden bugs?

Comment: not 100% sure if it does anything weird in the background, but I have been using a similar approach without finding any bad side effects

Answer (score 21):

[Arthur Vickers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2012410/arthur-vickers) defines a rule when `DetectChanges` doesn't need to be called (even not before `SaveChanges`) [in this blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/):

> No call to EF code will leave the context in a state where
>   DetectChanges needs to be called if it didn’t need to be called
>   before.

Regarding **Add** and **Delete** these are "EF code" methods because you either call `Add` or `Delete` or you set the state of `context.Entry(entity).State` to `Added` or `Deleted`. So, if you would just loop through a bunch of entites and add or delete them then you don't need to call `DetectChanges` at all.

Regarding **Edit** it is, I believe, a bit more subtle. When you update entities by using either...

```
context.Entry(entity).CurrentValues.SetValues(someObject);
```

...or by using the property API of `DbContext`...

```
context.Entry(entity).Property(e => e.SomeProperty).CurrentValue = someValue;
```

...then you don't need `DetectChanges` (even not before `SaveChanges`) either because these are again calls into "EF code".

If you just change property values of an entity like...

```
entity.SomeProperty = someValue;
```

...then the second rule [in the same blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/) linked above applies:

> Any time that non-EF code changes any property value of an entity or
>   complex object then DetectChanges may need to be called.

And I think you need in fact only one single call to `DetectChanges` before `SaveChanges` **if** you just loop through some entities, load them into or attach them to the context and change some (scalar and complex) property values.

If you do more complex stuff (maybe relationship changes? or something else?) your approach might not be safe anymore because

1. `AutoDetectChanges` would not be implemented in the way it is and called in many EF methods if it would be only necessary once right before `SaveChanges`
2. it is mentioned [in the same blog post](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2012/03/12/secrets-of-detectchanges-part-3-switching-off-automatic-detectchanges/) again that

   > If the code makes change changes to the properties of the entities
   >   instead of just calling Add or Attach, then, by Rule 2, DetectChanges
   >   will need to be called, at least as part of SaveChanges **and possibly
   >   also before** then.

   (Highlighting from me)

Unfortunately I don't know an example of code that would show when calling `DetectChanges` at earlier stages than right before `SaveChanges` is necessary. But because of point 1 above I am sure such examples exist.

Comment: That was a great post, thank you. But i am a little unclear (sorry for this): 1. Why EF needs to call DetectChanges so many times when it could just call DetectChanges before actually saving into database? 2. I am using `POCO` objects with normal properties (not marked with `virtual`). When i change the object properties values, does EF calls DetectChanges() silently?

Comment: @RaraituL: To point 1: I don't know. That's what I meant with my very last sentence. To point 2: No. `DetectChanges` is called later in `SaveChanges` and a bunch of other EF methods, not when you assign property values. `DetectChanges` compares then the current property values with the original values (that are stored as a "snapshot" in object context) and if the values changed the properties will be marked as modified. It's called "snapshot based change tracking".

Answer (score -1):

One of the main problems that can be resolved by `DetectChanges` is persisting data in EF when we have `ManyToMany` relation and `AutoDetectChanges=false`.