# DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled always True VS enabling just before SaveChanges()

Tags: performance, ef-code-first

I am trying to boost my EF operation performance, and I have found some recommendations regarding DbContext.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled property
a) in some cases to turn off AutoDetectChangesEnabled - this is clear - I am using it for import functions
b) but then I have noticed this type of approach with enabling this property only before calling SaveChanges():

```
DbContext db = new DbContext();
db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

//...some changes to POCO properties

db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = true;
db.SaveChanges();
```

all the changes seem to be correctly saved to database and it works noticably faster compared to approach where AutoDetectChangesEnabled property is leaved intact.

**Question**

So I wonder is there a reason to leave AutoDetectChangesEnabled intact? What risks there could be if I disable this property by default and then reenable each time before calling DbContext.SaveChanges?

**Related post**

This post suggests that there *might be* reasons to leave AutoDetectChangesEnabled==true, but no clear evidence when and why should do so (ok, it says - do so, if entities are **EDITED**). Has anybody found out argument for/against this?

[EF Code First: is good to call DetectChanges just before SaveChanges?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15342377/ef-code-first-is-good-to-call-detectchanges-just-before-savechanges)

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the documentation [Entity Framework Automatic Detect Changes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj556205) it says:

> When using most POCO entities the determination of how an entity has
>   changed (and therefore which updates need to be sent to the database)
>   is handled by the Detect Changes algorithm. Detect Changes works by
>   **detecting the differences between the current property values of the
>   entity and the original property values** that are stored in a snapshot
>   when the entity was queried or attached.

So I think this support the link that you found that if the entity is **Edited**, with AutoDetectChangesEnabled=true, the change is tracked.

I've been disabling the AutoDetectChangesEnabled for **Insert**, with great performance improvement.