# How to update many to many in Entity Framework with AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

Please, help me to handle this situation:

> I meaningly switched off `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` and I load my
>   entities `AsNoTracked()` meaningly either.
>
> And **I can't update many-to-many relationship in this case:**

Here is the code of Update method:

```
public void Update(User user)
{
  var userRoleIds = user.Roles.Select(x => x.Id);
  var updated = _users.Find(user.Id);

  if (updated == null)
  {
    throw new InvalidOperationException("Can't update user that doesn't exists in database");
  }

  updated.Name = user.Name;
  updated.LastName = user.LastName;
  updated.Login = user.Login;
  updated.Password = user.Password;
  updated.State = user.State;

  var newRoles = _roles.Where(r => userRoleIds.Contains(r.Id)).ToList();
  updated.Roles.Clear();
  foreach (var newRole in newRoles)
  {
    updated.Roles.Add(newRole);
  }

  _context.Entry(updated).State = EntityState.Modified;            
}
```

> All simple fields, like `Name`, `LastName` updated. **But the set
>   of Roles for User doesn't get updated - it stays the same.**

I tried loading Roles using

```
_context.Entry(updated).Collection("Roles").Load();
```

But I can't update this loaded set in any way.

I searched for similar items but failed to find the answer, thought it definitely already exists.

I'm really sorry for possible dublicate.

PS. I want to add that I don't want to delete or update child entities at all.
A lot of existing answers suggest `manually delete / add child entities to database in whole`, **but it is not suitable for me**.

> Roles are independent entities, any other user can use them.

**I just want to update `User_Role` table in database, but I can't.**

Comment: Did you invoke `SaveChanges()`  ?

Comment: I think `User_Role` you added is not tracked by entity framework, hence updating the entity is not reflected to the database. `Attach` and try to update `_context.User_Role Attach(yourEntity);` then try to update

Comment: I found one working way. Don't really know if it is sensible, but  _context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges(); works. I don't know if it possible to make the same manually.

Comment: Surely I invoked SaveChanges, but later, in UnitOfWork Commit() method.  No attaching, no updating child entities helps. Clild entities gets updated but not relationships between child and parent entities.

Comment: Take a look at the details of `context.ChangeTracker.DetectChanges();`
http://stackoverflow.com/a/15346082/1876572

I think to maintain relationship EF need to track the entities , Try the same without using `NoTracking()`