# Bulk insert with EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework, database-performance

I need to insert some objects (about 4 million) in the database using C# and EF (using .NET 3.5). My method that adds the objects is in a for:

```
 private DBModelContainer AddToContext(DBModelContainer db, tblMyTable item, int count)
        {
            db.AddTottblMyTable (item);
            if ((count % 10000== 0) || (count == this.toGenerate))
            {
                try
                {
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(e.StackTrace);
                }
            }
            return db;
        }
```

How to detach the added objects (of type tblMyTable) from the context object? I don't need them for a later use and when more than 300000 objects are added, the execution time between db saving ( db.SaveChanges()) increases considerably.

Regards

Comment: I don't think that using Entity Framework for bulk import is efficient, have you considered using `SqlBulkCopy`? Also, can you please add a code example of how you add the entities to the context?

Comment: Rather than "Detach", try turning off change tracking - AutoDetectChangesEnabled with: context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;

Comment: @reckface context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled is not available in .net 3.5

Comment: What version of EF do you have? Is this available:     context.tblMyTable.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; ?

Comment: I have EF V1 (I'm using .net 3.5) and context.tblMyTable.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking; it's available. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entity Framework may not be the best tool for this type of operation. You may be better off with plain ADO.Net, some stored procedures... But if you had to use it, here are a number of suggestions:

- Keep the active Context Graph small by using a new context for each
  Unit of Work
- Turn off AutoDetechChangesEnabled - context.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled = false;
- Batching, in your loop, Call SaveChanges periodically

**EDIT**

```
    using(var db = new DBModelContainer())
    {
       db.tblMyTable.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
       // Narrow the scope of your db context
       db.AddTottblMyTable (item);
       db.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Keeping a long running db context is not advisable, so consider refactoring your Add method to not keep attempting to reuse the same context.

See [Rick Strahl's post on bulk inserts for more details](http://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2013/Dec/22/Entity-Framework-and-slow-bulk-INSERTs)

Comment: If I'm creating new context object after db.SaveChanges(), I'm getting the exception "An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker"

Comment: My recommendation can't be used with the pattern you have: AddToContext(DBModelContainer db... To keep the active context graph small means, creating a context, adding the entities, calling save changes and disposing of it (using context = new DBModelContainer... I'll expand on this in the answer

Comment: If I'm using this approach, I call save for every item and it will take more time to add all the items...

Comment: Have you tried it? Have you read that blog post? Using the long running context, took 57 minutes for some 30,000 adds, shrinking the scope of the context went down to 33 seconds. The principles discussed there will apply to your situation.

Comment: If I'm creating a new context object in my for loop, I'm getting the error An entity object cannot be referenced by multiple instances of IEntityChangeTracker.   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityObject.System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithChangeTracker.SetChangeTracker(IEntityChangeTracker changeTracker)

But If I'm using 
                using (db)
                {
                    db.tblMyTable.MergeOption = MergeOption.NoTracking;
                    db.AddTotblMyTable(tr);
                    db.SaveChanges();
}

Comment: I'm getting the error The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.get_Connection()

Comment: and I need to use the context object outside my for loop to read some stuff from the database

Comment: Ok, I think you've got all you need to decide on a way forward. A long running context with no tracking or a narrow scoped context. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/data/jj729737.aspx warns: As you load more objects and their references into memory, the memory consumption of the context may increase rapidly...

Answer (score 2):

AFAK EF does not support directly  the BulkInsert so it will be tedious to  do such thing  manually.

try to consider [`EntityFramework.BulkInsert`](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/)

```
using (var ctx = GetContext())
{
  using (var transactionScope = new TransactionScope())
  {
    // some stuff in dbcontext

    ctx.BulkInsert(entities);

    ctx.SaveChanges();
    transactionScope.Complete();
  }
}
```

Comment: I don't have the method BulkInsert on my db object. Is this available in .NET 3.5 ?

Comment: is not a .net 3.5 method you have to download  https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/ and compile it for 3.5 and then you will get the Extension method for 3.5

Comment: @BudaGavril you can also get it via nuget nuget `Install-Package EntityFramework.BulkInsert-efx` (replace x with version number 4, 5 or 6)

Comment: I am not allowed to use third party libraries, only the classes from .net 3.5 framework

Comment: ok so download the source code and make it yours if you want  :)

Comment: this would mean that all the source code from that library would need to go trough code review and this can take time

Comment: I don't think so it will need just the time to compile as the library is in stable release and is faraway from a serious critical security vulnerabilities if this was your concern

Answer (score 0):

You may try Unit Of Work and dont save context (SaveChanges) on every record insert but save it at end

Comment: the count variable is the number of objects generated to be inserted. As you can see, only when I've added 10000 of reached to the total number of objects to generate I call saveChanges(), not for every item. What is Unit Of Work?

Comment: @BudaGavril, EF DbContext is an implementation of the Unit of Work pattern: http://www.wekeroad.com/2014/03/04/repositories-and-unitofwork-are-not-a-good-idea/

Comment: AddRange may help to save time

DataContext.Entity.AddRange(entityEnumerable);

Comment: the method db.tblMyTables.AddRange(entityEnumerable) it's not available, I'm using EF V1 (.net 3.5)