# Inserting many rows with Entity Framework is extremely slow

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I'm using Entity Framework to build a database.  There's two models; *Workers* and *Skills*.  Each *Worker* has zero or more *Skills*.  I initially read this data into memory from a CSV file somewhere, and store it in a dictionary called `allWorkers`.  Next, I write the data to the database as such:

```
// Populate database
using (var db = new SolverDbContext())
{
   // Add all distinct skills to database
   db.Skills.AddRange(allSkills
      .Distinct(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
      .Select(s => new Skill
      {
         Reference = s
      }));

   db.SaveChanges(); // Very quick
   var dbSkills = db.Skills.ToDictionary(k => k.Reference, v => v);

   // Add all workers to database
   var workforce = allWorkers.Values
      .Select(i => new Worker
      {
         Reference = i.EMPLOYEE_REF,
         Skills = i.GetSkills().Select(s => dbSkills[s]).ToArray(),
         DefaultRegion = "wa",
         DefaultEfficiency = i.TECH_EFFICIENCY
      });

   db.Workers.AddRange(workforce);
   db.SaveChanges(); // This call takes 00:05:00.0482197
}
```

The last `db.SaveChanges();` takes over five minutes to execute, which I feel is far too long.  I ran SQL Server Profiler as the call is executing, and basically what I found was thousands of calls to:

```
INSERT [dbo].[SkillWorkers]([Skill_SkillId], [Worker_WorkerId])
VALUES (@0, @1)
```

There are 16,027 rows being added to `SkillWorkers`, which is a fair amount of data but not huge by any means.  Is there any way to optimize this code so it doesn't take 5min to run?

**Update:** I've looked at other possible duplicates, [such as this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework), but I don't think they apply.  First, I'm not bulk adding anything in a loop.  I'm doing a single call to `db.SaveChanges();` after every row has been added to `db.Workers`.  This should be the fastest way to bulk insert.  Second, I've set `db.Configuration.AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to `false`.  The `SaveChanges()` call now takes *00:05:11.2273888* (In other words, about the same).  I don't think this really matters since every row is new, thus there are no *changes* to detect.

I think what I'm looking for is a way to issue a single UPDATE statement containing all 16,000 skills.

Comment: Have you tried searching? There's plenty of questions about bulk inserting in Entity Framework, see for example [Fastest Way of Inserting in Entity Framework](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework).

Comment: Possibly disabling autodetect changes: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5943394/why-is-inserting-entities-in-ef-4-1-so-slow-compared-to-objectcontext/5943699#5943699

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5940225/fastest-way-of-inserting-in-entity-framework to me.

Comment: Running again after setting `AutoDetectChangesEnabled` to false.  We'll see how much of a difference that makes.

Comment: Still about the same.

Comment: [Here is a third party library that makes handling bulk inserts easier](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/).

Comment: @Jdsfighter - Oh cool, that might be worth checking out!  Yea I was thinking about just crafting the INSERT statement myself and running it manually..

Comment: @Jdsfighter - Doh!  Looks like that library won't work in my situation.  `BulkInsert` doesn't also automatically insert referenced entities.  I also don't have a model for `WorkerSkills` so I can't create a bunch of those to Bulk Insert.  Bummer..

Comment: I haven't used it but heard good things about [EntifyFrameworkExtensions](https://github.com/loresoft/EntityFramework.Extended). Give it a try!!

Comment: @vendettamit - Looks like they have batched updates and deletes which is great, but nothing to bulk insert.

Comment: @Jdsfighter - I reworked my models to support the BulkInsert extension method.  The total time is now `00:00:01.1812081`, way cool!  Feel free to add this as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One easy method is by using the [EntityFramework.BulkInsert](https://efbulkinsert.codeplex.com/) extension.

You can then do:

```
// Add all workers to database
var workforce = allWorkers.Values
   .Select(i => new Worker
   {
      Reference = i.EMPLOYEE_REF,
      Skills = i.GetSkills().Select(s => dbSkills[s]).ToArray(),
      DefaultRegion = "wa",
      DefaultEfficiency = i.TECH_EFFICIENCY
   });

db.BulkInsert(workforce);
```