# Entity framework: How to return a row from a table with composite keys?

Tags: entity-framework, return, row, composite-key

```
  public class UserBuilding
    {
        [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
        public int UserId { get; set; }
        [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
        public int BuildingId { get; set; }
        public int BuildingLevel { get; set; }
    }
```

If I wanted to return all the different buildings that belong to a user, I would do the following:

```
database.UserBuildings.Where(b => b.UserId == userId);
```

My question is what if I wanted to return a specific building from a specific user? What would be the most 'efficient' way of doing this? Is there a better way (such as a built-in function) than the following:

```
database.UserBuildings.Where(b => b.UserId == userId && b.BuildingId == buildingId);
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you are lookding for [DbSet.Find](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696418%28v=vs.103%29.aspx) method. This method finds entity by primary key. If you have composite primary key, then pass key values in the order they defined in model:

```
var userBuilding = database.UserBuildings.Find(userId, buildingId);
```

Comment: works like a charm thank you! Do you think this would be considered "more efficient" in terms of the speed of the algorithm?

Comment: @Deniz Find first checks if entity already in context before querying database, so yes, its more efficient

Comment: @Deniz: `Find` can actually be much slower if the entity is *not* loaded (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11686225/dbset-find-method-ridiculously-slow-compared-to-singleordefault-on-id). Rule of thumb, maybe: Use `Find` if it is likely that the object is already in the context. If you know that it isn't loaded yet or it is very unlikely, use the query in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the input, in my case the entity will always definitely be there. I will bear that in mind.

Comment: @Slauma thanks, didn't know that Find is *much* slower if entity is not in context. BTW is there any tests of performance?

Comment: @lazyberezovsky: Regarding `Find` I only know the measurement in the linked question. Generally automatic change detection in `DbContext` ( = the internal `DetectChanges` call that occurs in many EF methods) is notorious for being slow (`Attach` is another example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5921259/270591. Or `Add`: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5943699/270591). But in cases where only a few entities are attached to the context it doesn't matter. It's usually only to consider for "bulk operations".