# How to update a record with composite primary key in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a model with a primary key made up of two columns in it

```
public class UserSite
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public string User_Name { get; set; }
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public string Site_Code { get; set; }
    public bool Default_site { get; set; }
    public DateTime Last_Modified { get; set; }
}
```

Now I want to update a record. I am using a generic repository concept.

```
 public void Edit(TEntity entity)
 {
            context.Entry(entity).State = EntityState.Modified;
            Save();
 }
```

When I try to call this edit using unit of work iam getting the following error

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.StackOverflowException' occurred.

Please help

Thanks in advance

Comment: This code does not throw that exception. Show the top of the stack trace.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781777/entity-framework-how-to-return-a-row-from-a-table-with-composite-keys

Comment: @Scherling I want to update the record not to find it

Comment: Once you found it, updating it is only a matter of setting a value and doing a context.SaveChanges(). Edit: But yeah, I guess this question might be somewhat different

Comment: @CodeCaster Debugging is stopping if i say continue

Comment: @Alicek can you should your Save method?