# Check if some value already exist in database ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can I check if some value already exist in database I am doing MVC with Entity Framework and I want to check if element with composite key already exist in database application does someone has any suggestion i GOT the Json object but my done() method doesn't work?

I tried with JsonResult method from my controller

```
public JsonResult Check(int? id1, int? id2)
    {
        IQueryable<InspekcijskaKontrola> listaKontrola = db.InspekcijskeKontrole.Include(i => i.InspekcijskaTijela).Include(i => i.Proizvod).Select(i => i);

        InspekcijskaKontrola inKontrola = listaKontrola.Where(i => i.InspekcijskoTijeloId == id1).Where(i => i.ProizvodId == id2).Select(i => i).Single();
        if (inKontrola!=null)
        {
            return Json(inKontrola, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(new InspekcijskaKontrola { InspekcijskoTijeloId = -1, ProizvodId = -1 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

And I tried to rised modal dialog from my view with script

```
function prikazi() {
    var zahtjev = $.getJSON("/InspekcijskeKontrole/Check?id1=" + $("#kombo3").val() + "&id2=" + $("#kombo4").val());

    zahtjev.done(function (kontrola) {

        if (kontrola.InspekcijskoTijeloId != -1 && kontrola.ProizvodId != -1) {
            $("#p1").text("Inspekcijska kontrola za " + kontrola.ProizvodId + " je vec izvrsena");
            $("#modalni1").modal({ backdrop: "static" });
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Provide some code what you've already tried here. Some ways to check existing values in DB are through SQL query or LINQ with lambda expressions.

Comment: It depends on what you use to communicate with the database. Are you using Entity Framework?

Comment: Yes I am using EF and I have composite key and I want to check if value with that key already exist in database if is so to pop up some message

Comment: Then it looks like the place to go for you is an Entity Framework tutorial, not Stack Overflow. Read [ask] and share your research.

Comment: See for example [Entity framework: How to return a row from a table with composite keys?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14781777/entity-framework-how-to-return-a-row-from-a-table-with-composite-keys) and [Best way to check if object exists in Entity Framework?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802286/best-way-to-check-if-object-exists-in-entity-framework).

Comment: I tried JsonResult method to get object with that composite key and from java script I tried to call that method and if object exist to rise modal dialog with informations, Can i do it in create ActionResult now when I check this JsonResult method I got circular reference excpetion?

Comment: I got the object with `db.InspekcijskeKontroles.Find(int id1, int id2);`

Answer (score -1):

Providing a bit of code would really help. However, right off the bat I could suggest you use something like this to search for a key(or more) from an object:

```
if(dbContext.Items.Any(anyObjectName=>anyObjectName.firstKey == ValueYouLookFor 
                                   && anyObjectName.secondkey == AnotherValue))
{
    //logic to apply if object exists
}
```

Comment: better solution is Find(id1,id2) on dbSet

Comment: Indeed, if the values are all part of the key, find works, but if you look for something like a user with an ID and his name, where the only key is the ID, it wouldn't work, you'd have to use either the Any(to check if it exists) method, or the First/FirstOrDefault(to get the object if it exists). Anyway, glad you found your solution, and good luck in the future